Explanation of answer in Abbott 4.3.1
I recently attempted to do exercise 4.3.1 in Abbott’s book Understanding Analysis which asks us to prove that $g(x) = x^{1/3}$ is continuous. I proved the claim for $x = 0$ but it seemed that proving the $x \neq 0$ was simply beyond my ken, so I gave up and looked up the answer in the solution manual. However, that solution is very confusing to me. Here it is:
(b) For $c \neq 0$ write,
$$
|g(x) - g(c)| = \left|\sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{c}\right| = \left|\sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{c}\right| \left(\frac{\sqrt[3]{x^2} + \sqrt[3]{xc} + \sqrt[3]{c^2}}{\sqrt[3]{x^2} + \sqrt[3]{xc} + \sqrt[3]{c^2}}\right)
$$
$$
= \frac{|x - c|}{\sqrt[3]{x^2} + \sqrt[3]{xc} + \sqrt[3]{c^2}} \leq \frac{|x - c|}{\sqrt[3]{c^2}}.
$$
Therefore, if we pick
$
\delta = \epsilon \sqrt[3]{c^2}, \text{ then } |x - c| < \delta = \epsilon \sqrt[3]{c^2} \text{ implies}
$
$$
|g(x) - g(c)| = |\sqrt[3]{x} - \sqrt[3]{c}| \leq \frac{|x - c|}{\sqrt[3]{c^2}} < \frac{\epsilon \sqrt[3]{c^2}}{\sqrt[3]{c^2}} = \epsilon.
$$
From my perspective, the way Abbott manipulates $|x^{1/3} - c^{1/3}|$ into something more tractable appears to come from nowhere, as if it were a lucky guess. I presume it actually was not, and that I just don’t see the reasoning. So my question is: how could I have discovered for myself in a reasonable manner that $\frac{x^{2/3} + (xc)^{1/3} + c^{2/3}}{x^{2/3} + (xc)^{1/3} + c^{2/3}}$ is the appropriate expression to multiply $|x^{1/3} - c^{1/3}|$ by in order to get an expression in terms of $|x - c|$ and a constant?

The idea behind that choice is the identity: $a^{3} - b^{3} = (a - b)(a^{2} + ab + b^{2})$, which is applied to $a = \sqrt[3]{x}$ and $b = \sqrt[3]{c}$.
